# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

На Nexus 7 c Android 5.0(не 4.4) происходит крах с *Exception* из заголовка. После непродолжительных поисков был найден следующий [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489703/trying-to-remove-fragment-from-view-gives-me-nullpointerexception-on-mnextanim). Меня он не устраивает, так как в силу обстоятельств не могу отказаться от *android.support.v4.app.*

Возможность операции над фрагментом, равным null, я тоже рассматривал, но такого быть не должно. Отрывок кода под подозрением:

```
String tag = FRAGMENT_STATE;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
...
stateFragment = new Fragment();
...
if (stateFragment != null) {
...
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();//.support.v4
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, stateFragment, tag);
...          
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Еще есть следующий отрывок:

```
  //Типо подключаю фрагменты
  if(onerFragment == null) Logi.d("OneFragment is Null");
  //if (oneFragment == null || twoeFragment == null) {
  Logi.d("блок подключения фрагментов");
  fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  Logi.d("oneGragment constructer before");
  oneFragment = new OneGragment();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.one_fragment, oneFragment);
  Logi.d("TwoFragment constructer before");
  twoFragment = new TwoFragment();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.two_fragment, twoFragment);

  fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Логи:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Process: название пакета, PID: 7755
>    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
>       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:709)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

P.S Устройства у меня нет, логи взяты из *GoogleTestLab*, тестирование на эмуляторе тоже не смогу. есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи что делать с этим "эксепшеном"?

Comment: Во второй части, Вы проверяете если 1 или 2 фрагмент null - начинаете транзакцию, мб забыли поставить не null. !null

Comment: Проверку эту я закоментил. Удаляю и добавляю вручную

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393707) сказано:
Это происходит из-за того, что Вы вызываете методы `remove()`, `add()` и т.п. со значением `null`.

Поразумевается, что `replace()` - это `remove()` и за ним `add()`.

Comment: Думаешь мне поможет что то в духе fragmentManager.getFragment(R.id.fragment_id) == null, то делаем адд, иначе репласе

Comment: @jangorussia, да, думаю именно это и имеет в виду автор ответа)